# Axios in Node - Download files loop returns invalid data

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm trying to download files from my web server using Node and Axios. I am iterating through an array of 'sounds.' The result of the code is the correct number of files exist, with correct filenames, but, the sizes are incorrect and the data is invalid.

```
boardData.sounds.forEach((sound) => {
    console.log(sound.sound_transcript);
    //Download sound
    var sound_filename = boardSounds_dir + sound.id + '.mp3';
    console.log(sound_filename);

    axios({
        url: baseURL + sound.sound_file_url,
        method: 'GET',
        repsonseType: 'blob'
    })
        .then((response) => {
            //Handle success
            console.log('Load success');
            fs.writeFile(sound_filename, response.data, (err) => {
                if (err) throw 'error writing file: ' + err;
                console.log('File written');
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            //Handle error
            console.error('Load error:', error.message);
            //throw error.message;
        })
        .then(() => {
            //Always executed
        });
});
```

I believe this is something to do with multiple instances existing at the same time and overwriting each other, but I would appreciate help figuring out what to do.

Comment: is `response.data` as expected? what did you mean by "data is invalid"

Comment: may be you have to provide encoding info as described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback). `fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', 'utf8', callback);`

Comment: Hashan: I tried 'binary' in the fs.writeFile and 'utf8' but no good. The response.data is as expected, but the files that are saved are not valid MP3 files. I'm really confused.

Comment: I ended up using
                response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./assets-downloaded/sounds/potato.jpg'))
I will have to do some reading to learn some more